# Get position in a pdf-page by clicking for annoting a pdf with latex

Tags: latex, pdf, pdf-tools

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85676/4011, it is illustrated of how to annotated a pdf by using the latex package [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), loading the pdf as a background layer and then use [`tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) nodes to make annotations at coordinates `(x,y)` (compare [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file) for similar approaches). The problem is that you need to get the coordinates of where you want to make the annotations manually by reading it from a overlayed coordinate system.

How can I use [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) to get the coordinate automatically by just clicking on the place where I want to insert the annotation?